# Error with list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's uncomfortable code, I know, and sorry. Especially, if it's a stupid question.

Here is an error with list, and I don't know why (I'm beginner). Can someone, please, tell me, how to fix it?

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/milom/PycharmProjects/ChislM/method.py", line 77, in <module>
    vx, vy = rk3(diff1, 0, U0, 10, 100)
  File "C:/Users/milom/PycharmProjects/ChislM/method.py", line 39, in rk3
    x,v=step(f, h, i, x0, U0)
  File "C:/Users/milom/PycharmProjects/ChislM/method.py", line 11, in step
    k2 = f(x[i] + (1 / 3) * h[i], v[i] + (1 / 3) * k1)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
import pandas as pd

x =[0]*101
v =[0]*101

def step(f, h, i, x0, U0):
    x[0] = x0
    v[0] = U0
    k1 = f(x[i], v[i])
    k2 = f(x[i] + (1 / 3) * h[i], v[i] + (1 / 3) * k1)
    k3 = f(x[i] + (2 / 3) * h[i], v[i] + (2 / 3) * h[i] * k2)
    x[i] = x[i - 1] + h[i]
    v[i] = v[i - 1] + (h[i]) * ((1 / 4) * k1 + (3 / 4) * k3)
    return x, v


def rk3(f, x0, U0, x1, n):
    h = [(x1 - x0) / float(n)]
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        x,v=step(f, h, i, x0, U0)
        ###h= control(f, h[i], i, v[i], x0, U0)
    return x, v


def diff1(x, U):
    return 0.1


def diff(x, U):
    return -(m.cos(10 * x) + ((m.log(1 + x ** 2)) / (1 + x)) * (U ** 2) + U)


def exact_path():
    plt.grid()
    plt.plot(vx, vy)
    plt.show()


def table():
    mytable = pd.DataFrame({
        'Xn': vx,
        'Vn': vy,
    }, index=[i for i in range(0, 101)])
    mytable.index.name = 'number'
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    print(mytable)


task = int(input("Task:"))
U0 = float(input("First value- U0:"))

if task == 2:
    vx, vy = rk3(diff, 0, U0, 10, 100)
    table()
    exact_path()

if task == 1:
    vx, vy = rk3(diff1, 0, U0, 10, 100)
    table()
    exact_path()
```

P.S. It's a simple 3th order Runge-Kutta method, but mostly problem with synthax. I tried to implement method with Python.

Comment: In `rk3` switch from 100 to 99 because when you try to iterate to `n+1`, the index goes up to 101. Your list has indexes from 0 to 100 and thus it throws an `IndexError`.

Comment: Welcome.  The key answer is in the traceback.  An `IndexError` is raised when you try to reference something with an invalid index.  Consider `a = [1, 2]`.  The statement `print(a[2])` will raise an `IndexError` because `2` is not a valid index.  Take a look at line 11 of your code and consider whether `index [i]` is valid for objects x, h, and v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `rk3()` function you have `h = [(x1 - x0) / float(n)]` which creates an list with only a single element in it. This means that the only valid non-negative index that can be used with it would be `h[0]`—and an attempt to use any other index value, as is likely in the `step()` function in the `for` loop, will cause an `IndexError`.